# How many permutations are there of the letters, taken all at a time, if the word

Tags: permutations

How many permutations are there of the letters, taken all at a time, if the words

(a) ASSESSES

(b) PATTIVEERANPATTI

Ans:

(a) $$\frac{8!}{5!\cdot2!} = 168$$

(b) $$\frac{16!}{2!\cdot3!\cdot4!\cdot2!\cdot2!}$$

Are these the correct answers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your answers are correct.

If you had 8 different letters there would be 8! ways of arranging them. However there are 5 S's so these can be interchanged in 5! ways. Similarly there are 2 E's so these can be interchanged in 2! ways.

Same argument for the second answer.